# serialise Date object to JSON using Gson in a custom way (annotation)

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I've got a following structure of classes

```
class A {
  B b;
}

class B {
    @CustomDateFormat(
        format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    )
    protected Date creationDate;
}
```

I'd like to serialise an instance of class A to JSON in the way that the output JSON has creationDate field formatted using the value in the annotation @CustomDateFormat. Is it possible? Ideally using Gson. That will be executed on Android so no Java 8 features ATM.

thanks in advance for any ideas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I used reflection, went through the tree of objects and created a relation Date -> String (format). Then created a custom serializer and used the mentioned map to format date accordingly. Thanks for the answers though!!

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible?

Sort of. Unfortunately, Gson almost does not support custom annotations. However, Gson does native support for its `@JsonAdapter` annotation, so that you can emulate a custom annotation.

Let's say,

```java
final class A {

    final B b;

    A(final B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

```java
final class B {

    // Here comes an emulation for @CustomDateFormat(format = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonAdapter(YyyyMmDdDateTypeAdapter.class)
    final Date creationDate;

    B(final Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

}
```

```java
abstract class AbstractDateTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<Date> {

    protected abstract DateFormat getDateFormat();

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public final void write(final JsonWriter out, final Date value)
            throws IOException {
        out.value(getDateFormat().format(value));
    }

    @Override
    public final Date read(final JsonReader in) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
    }

}
```

```java
final class YyyyMmDdDateTypeAdapter
        extends AbstractDateTypeAdapter {

    // Let Gson do it itself when needed
    private YyyyMmDdDateTypeAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    protected DateFormat getDateFormat() {
        // SimpleDateFormat is known to be thread-unsafe so it has to be created everytime it's necessary
        // Maybe Joda Time is an option for you?
        // Joda Time date formatters are thread-safe and can be safely instantiated once per application
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }

}
```

Example:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

public static void main(final String... args) {
    final A a = new A(new B(new Date()));
    final String json = gson.toJson(a);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Output:

> {"b":{"creationDate":"2017-05-29"}}

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `@CustomDataFormat` is constant then you can use below code

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").create();
```

If it is not constant then I think you have to go for reflection to read annotated value and then apply on the above code.

Comment: It's not constant indeed. However using reflection it's also not trivial cause I don't know which exactly Date member is being serialized

e.g.

new JsonSerializer<Date>() {

            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                // in most cases yyyy-MM-dd is used, therefore keep it as a fallback
                String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
}
}

Comment: In other words...I would have to build a tree out of a class with Fields as members. That would give me back the annotations. Finally orchestrate those with a custom JsonSerializer<Date>. It looks to me v. hacky but have no better idea